# What is "PMEasyView"?

Tags: malware

I got a little toast pop up just now saying "hello world, PMEasyView!" I just woke up my phone, was in the SugarSync app. I haven't recently installed anything except from the Android Market and Amazon market; nothing named like PM Easy View.

The wording sounds like something I would have written in a development Android app. I don't see any unusual running processes or apps, so I'm wondering if it's dummy code from a real app I own, but I was hoping someone knew for sure. I'm having Lookout scan my phone now.

All I found on this topic was [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1368379) which has no answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system app, PerformanceManager.apk has the line Hello World, PMEasyView! in the resources.arsc file. This does not appear to be malware, just a mistake that this appears to some users with the Motorola Task / Performance Manager.

Comment: Hm, it is a Motorla phone; that may well be it!

Comment: Please see [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) If you want to add links that are relevant to your answer then feel free, but Stack Exchange answers are not a medium for you to plug your site for free. You can put links to your websites or professional works in your profile.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely to be a debugging message from a program you've installed that the programmer forgotten to remove. If you want to seek which program that does it; you can try to copy all installed applications (android apps are installed from market are in /data/app/, pre-installed apps are in /system/app/), unzip them (an .apk is basically a zip file with a certain directory structure), and search which ones contains the string (you can use grep in Linux/Mac or find in Windows).

If you do found out which are the offending app, please post it here to save other people from the hassle.

Comment: Never saw it again, must have been a debug message someone left in, an update probably fixed it. Didn't catch the app I'm afraid